# How to change global variable using other file by importing

Tags: python, variables, global, operator-keyword

I have made this calculator on Python with GUI using *Tkinter*, it's my university project but there are some requirements and one is that every function should be imported in the main GUI file not to be placed there.

For example, I have created a null operator textinput for textvariable and buttons from 1 to 9 and defined a button click handler function for it:

```
def btnClick(numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator+str(numbers)
    text_Input.set(operator)
```

And I have saved this in the other file called "Buttons.py"

Now when i call it in my gui file like this and make a button to execute it

```
import Buttons
button7=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=4,fg='black',font=('The Citadels',20),
           text='7',command=lambda:Buttons.btnClick(7),bg='ghost white')
    .grid(row=5,column=0)
```

But get an error saying

> name 'operator' is not defined

What is missing for my code to work ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `import` statement on its own, you import the module but you don't import the namespace. `operators` is not defined because it is part of the module's namespace. To fix this, you can either use `Buttons.operator` instead of `operator`, or you can change your import statement to look like `from Buttons import *`, which will import all the variables from `Buttons` into your namespace as well.

Comment: But operator is already defined in main file where button is present :/

Comment: can you provide the entire source code of both of your files?

Comment: its a very long code and i have created many more functions other than just "def btnClick" i tried your Buttons.operator and it worked, but the problem is i have created more files for other functions and also have to import those in main gui file so operator wont work with them if i make it "Buttons.operator".

Comment: "operator won't work with them if I make it "Buttons.operator" - I do understand why you can't reference `Buttons.operator` wherever you need it. Just add the import statement in each file that needs to reference it. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Can i reach you personally somehow? Skype or something so i can share my screen and make you understand?

Comment: Ok so i made 2 different files now 1) for functions 2) to import every function in it. Now imported the second file named "Collection" in my main gui with every function in it and placed Collection.etc_function in every place necessary but when i run it, it gives me an error saying module "Collection" has no attribute "btnClick".

Comment: Unless you want to pay me, I won't do screen sharing. Add a link to your source files either on github, or as a gist, or pastebin, or just here. Just show the sources.